# How do I remove duplicates from a list of strings?

Tags: python

I need help with this list. I don't now how to solve this.

I have this list

```
s = [['aaa', 'bbb'], ['ccc', 'bbb'], ['bbb', 'ddd'], ['fff', 'ddd'], ['ccc', 'eee']]
```

I want to delete the duplicates from this list.

Output must be:

```
[['aaa', 'bbb'], ['fff', 'ddd'],['ccc', 'eee']]
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what's supposed to be happening here - are you attempting to remove all sub-lists containing non-unique strings whilst ensuring that any strings that were present in the original list(s) are included somewhere in the output?

Comment: Yes I want to remove all sub-list, if containing non-unique strings.

Comment: Would you mind editing the original question to clarify this please? Also, how would you expect semi-unique sub-lists like this to be handled: `[['aaa', 'bbb'], ['ccc', 'aaa'], ['ddd', 'eee']]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
s = [['aaa', 'bbb'], ['ccc', 'bbb'], ['bbb', 'ddd'], ['fff', 'ddd'], ['ccc', 'eee']]

flaten = [ j for i in s for j in i ]
filter_l = list(set(flaten))

res = []
for ele in s:
    if ele[0] in filter_l and ele[1] in filter_l :
        res.append(ele)
        filter_l.remove(ele[0])
        filter_l.remove(ele[1])

print res

output : [['aaa', 'bbb'], ['fff', 'ddd'], ['ccc', 'eee']]
```

Well there can be more optimised way to achieve it but this is what i got.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the following code?

```
s = [['aaa', 'bbb'], ['ccc', 'bbb'], ['bbb', 'ddd'], ['fff', 'ddd'], ['ccc', 'eee']]

def get_unique_pairs(pairs):
    unique_pairs = []
    for pair in pairs:
        unique_pairs_flattened = [x for p in unique_pairs for x in p]
        if not (pair[0] in unique_pairs_flattened or pair[1] in unique_pairs_flattened):
            unique_pairs.append(pair)

    return unique_pairs

print(get_unique_pairs(s))  # => [['aaa', 'bbb'], ['fff', 'ddd'],['ccc', 'eee']]
```